# Same Technic is not working to update and delete while loop records

Tags: php, html, css

I used from this code 
      Delete Banner 
to delete the while loop record, but now I used the same thing to update the record from while loop, it doesn't give an error but it's not working even I checked the query one by one is correct.

```
    <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
    if(isset($_POST['deleteId'])){
    $query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_GET['deleteId']}'"; 
    $result5=mysqli_query($db,$query5); }

    ?>
    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['saveId'])){
   $fileName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
   $fileTmpName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
   $folder='images/';
   $title=$_POST['title'];
   $status=$_POST['status'];
   move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$folder.$fileName);
   $query6 = "UPDATE dones SET title='$title', image='$fileName', 
   status='$status' WHERE id='{$_GET['saveId']}'";
   $result6=mysqli_query($db,$query6); 
   }

  ?>
  <!--  Loop when new banner create it can dispaly new banner -->
  <?php
  $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
  $query="SELECT * FROM dones where id>3";
  $result1=mysqli_query($db,$query);

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
 {

  echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
  echo '<div class="card" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">';
   echo '<div class="card-header">';
     echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
     echo '<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
      echo  '<button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; font- 
   family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; " type="button" 
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
   aria-controls="collapseOne">';
      echo   $row['title'];

       echo '</button>';
      echo '</h5>';
    echo '</div>';

   echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria- 
  labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';
   echo  '<div class="card-body">';

   // Content Of new banner


   echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"> 
   <small>Title</small></h5>';
   echo '<input style="width:290px; margin-left:158px; height:30px; margin- 
   top:-30px;" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Title">';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <div class="custom-file" style="height:10px; width:290px; margin  
   right:1050px; top-padding:20px; float:right;">';
   echo ' <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="custom-file-input" 
   id="validatedCustomFile">';
   echo ' <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose 
   file...</label>';
   echo ' </div>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>File</small> 
   </h5>';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>Banner 
   Image</small></h5>';
   echo ' <div style="height:130px; width:290px; border-width:1px; border- 
   style:solid; float:right; margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-15px;">';


     $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
     $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
     $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<img src= "images/'.$data['image'].'" style="height:130px; 
     width:290px;">';

     echo '</div>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';  
     echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"> 
     <small>Status</small></h5>';
     echo '<select name="status" id="" style="width:290px; float:right; 
     margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-25px;">';
     echo '<option value="1" name="enable">Enable</option>';
     echo '<option value="0" name="disable">Disable</option>';
     echo '</select>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<button type="submit"   style="margin-left:250px;" class="btn 
     btn-primary"><a href="?saveId='. $row['id']. '">Save Banner</a> 
     </button>';  
     echo '<button type="submit" name="deletesubmit"  style="margin- 
    left:250px;"  class="btn btn-primary"><a href="?deleteId='. $row['id']. 
     '">Delete Banner</a></button>'; 
     echo '</div>';

     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';



    echo  '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  }   

  ?>
```

I can delete now, but I can't do update the records even I used the same methood.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable for sql injection, consider using prepare statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dones");
if(isset($_POST['deleteId'])){
    $query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_GET['deleteId']}'";
    $result5=mysqli_query($db,$query5); }

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['saveId'])){

    $fileName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $fileTmpName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $folder='images/';
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$folder.$fileName);
    $query6 = "UPDATE dones SET title='$title', image='$fileName', status='$status' WHERE id='".$_POST['saveId']."'";
    $result6=mysqli_query($db,$query6);
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}

?>
<!--  Loop when new banner create it can dispaly new banner -->
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dones");
$query="SELECT * FROM dones where id>3";
$result1=mysqli_query($db,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{

    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
    echo '<div class="card" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">';
    echo '<div class="card-header">';
    echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
    ?><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <?php
    echo  '<button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; font- 
   family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; " type="button" 
   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
   aria-controls="collapseOne">';
    echo   $row['title'];

    echo '</button>';
    echo '</h5>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria- 
  labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';
    echo  '<div class="card-body">';

    // Content Of new banner


    echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"> 
   <small>Title</small></h5>';
    echo '<input style="width:290px; margin-left:158px; height:30px; margin- 
   top:-30px;" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Title">';
    echo ' <br>';
    echo ' <div class="custom-file" style="height:10px; width:290px; margin  
   right:1050px; top-padding:20px; float:right;">';
    echo ' <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="custom-file-input" 
   id="validatedCustomFile">';
    echo ' <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose 
   file...</label>';
    echo ' </div>';
    echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>File</small> 
   </h5>';
    echo ' <br>';
    echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>Banner 
   Image</small></h5>';
    echo ' <div style="height:130px; width:290px; border-width:1px; border- 
   style:solid; float:right; margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-15px;">';


    $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<img src= "images/'.$data['image'].'" style="height:130px; 
     width:290px;">';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"> 
     <small>Status</small></h5>';
    echo '<select name="status" id="" style="width:290px; float:right; 
     margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-25px;">';
    echo '<option value="1" name="enable">Enable</option>';
    echo '<option value="0" name="disable">Disable</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    ?><button type="submit" name="saveId" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"  style="margin-left:250px;" class="btn
     btn-primary">Save Banner
     </button>
    <?php
    echo '<button type="submit" name="deletesubmit"  style="margin- 
    left:250px;"  class="btn btn-primary"><a href="?deleteId='. $row['id'].
        '">Delete Banner</a></button>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';



    echo  '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

Here is the fixed code

Comment: change the db connections

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `$_POST` and `$_GET` together, you need to make sure which method you are using, from your code, I guess it is `$_POST`, check your form, if the method is `$_POST`, then change whatever `$_GET` you have to `$_POST`.

Also, if you are using `$_GET`, make sure you are setting the variable named `saveId` is exist.

Comment: Even I used the same method $_POST but no result and the variable name is also correct

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't delete is at this point

```
$query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_GET['deleteId']}'"
```

Meanwhile a post data was the 1 sent here

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteId'])){
```

So if I am correct you should do it this way

```
$query5 = "DELETE FROM dones WHERE id='{$_POST['deleteId']}'"
```

Comment: hope u dont mind if i have to change your code from the way it is now

Comment: if u dont mind then please update your question with the curren page full code snippet so i help u fix

Comment: OK, man what you want I am telling delete is working I used the same method for update, but that is not working

Comment: i understand just do update the code above with the complete code for dis page so i can help you fix it now

Comment: i mean your original post code to the complete page code so i can study it all and fix it

Comment: (Note that this code has a serious SQL injection code vulnerability - even if the original code was from the question author, it is essential that the question author is notified of this danger.)

Comment: yea i notified him of it its now left for him to fix it check my previous comment i showed him how to do that using mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$unescapedString)

Answer (score 0):

here is your error line you checked if isset($_POST['saveId']) meanwhile the button doesnt have a name of save id;

```
echo '<button type="submit"   style="margin-left:250px;" class="btn 
     btn-primary"><a href="?saveId='. $row['id']. '">Save Banner</a> 
     </button>';
```

do this at this point instead

```
echo '<button type="submit" name="saveId" style="margin-left:250px;" class="btn 
         btn-primary"><a href="?saveId='. $row['id']. '">Save Banner</a> 
         </button>';
```

but do note this isn't good programming practice of setting at same time post and get inside each other.. also use mysqli_real_escape_string() to protect yourself from sql injection.

Comment: then try putting an echo here if it echoes then i knw what to do next

Comment: if(isset($_POST['saveId'])){ echo "in";
   $fileName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
   $fileTmpName=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
   $folder='images/';
   $title=$_POST['title'];
   $status=$_POST['status'];
   move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$folder.$fileName);
   $query6 = "UPDATE dones SET title='$title', image='$fileName', 
   status='$status' WHERE id='{$_GET['saveId']}'";
   $result6=mysqli_query($db,$query6); 
   }

Comment: Again no result, do one thing else copy my code and try with your self if you find any way for me, because it's very important for me

Comment: den send me your db file on google drive and share me a link to download it

Comment: give me your email

Comment: spartacusyusuf@yahoo.com

Comment: do send your css and script files also